# Why are there double question marks in JDBC code

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm in the process of converting JDBC sql statements over to ODBC/DB2 with PHP. I came across the following clause that confuses me.

```
WHERE phid = ??id
```

My first instinct was that it was for prepared statements, but now I'm not so sure. Is this a JSP/JDBC thing? Google/stack haven't turned up anything.

Comment: Can you post the code block where you have found this?

Comment: This isn't standard JDBC, might be a vendor specific extension.

Comment: Or it might be some application specific (named) parameter handling.

Comment: Can you post more of the java code?  The full sql prepared statement and any `setString` calls on it.

Answer (score 1):

Whoa!  Mabye it is just a normal bind variable, but having 2 in a row!  There is nothing in the documentation of [java.sql.Conneciton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) (quick read) that says they have to be separated by spaces.  Please post more code so we can see if there are any `setString` calls to add the bind variable(s).

For example, something like this:

```
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select blah from blah WHERE phid = ??id and blah blah");
pstmt.setString(1, "customer_");
pstmt.setString(2, "order_");
```

I've never seen anything like this, but maybe this is what they were doing?

**EDIT:** I tried it!  And it gave me an error!  I wonder if you found some dead code?  This is what I tried:

```
    sql.append("SELECT A.ID, A.GROUP_NUMBER, A.GROUP_NAME ");
    sql.append("FROM " + tab1 + " A ");
    sql.append("INNER JOIN " + tab2 + " B ");
    sql.append("ON (A.ID = B.GROUP_ID) ");
    sql.append("WHERE B.THREAD_ID = ? ");
    sql.append("AND B.THREAD_ID = ??ID ");
    sql.append("ORDER BY A.ID ");

// ...

        conn = getConn();
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        pstmt.setInt(1, threadId);
        pstmt.setString(2, "B.");
        pstmt.setString(3, "THREAD_");
```

I got this error:

`ILLEGAL SYMBOL "?". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: MICROSECONDS MICROSECOND SECONDS SECOND MINUTES MINUTE HOURS. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.57.82`

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented (sorry, don't have enough rep to comment yet), this is probably some way of named parameter handling. I can't find any references to it in neither JDBC nor any ORM frameworks I know, so it might be a custom JDBC/ORM framework created for that particular application. Seeing some more example code would certainly help.